Hessian and the second fundamental form
I am trying to relate the shape operator with the Hessian. I wish to motivate my question with an example.
Consider $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1$. Then $\nabla f = (2x,2y) =: 2N$ does not vanish on $M := f^{-1}(0)$. Recall that the shape operator $L : T_pM \rightarrow T_pM$ is given at each $p \in M$ by $L(X_p) := - D_{X_p}N$, where $D$ is the directional derivative. The matrix of this shape operator can be found using $\langle L(\partial_i),\partial_j\rangle$ where $\{\partial_{x,p},\partial_{y,p}\}$ form a basis at $T_pM$. We get that $$L = \begin{pmatrix}\langle L(\partial_x),\partial_x\rangle & \langle L(\partial_x),\partial_y\rangle \\ \langle L(\partial_y),\partial_x\rangle & \langle L(\partial_y),\partial_y\rangle\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}.$$On the other hand, the Hessian of $f$ reads $$Hf = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$
To add on this, we have the second fundamental form which reads $\Pi(X_p,Y_p) := \langle L(X_p),Y_p\rangle$. This bilinear form can be written as a matrix for $$\Pi = \begin{pmatrix}\Pi(e_1,e_1) & \Pi(e_1,e_2)\\ \Pi(e_2,e_1) & \Pi(e_2,e_2)\end{pmatrix}.$$So, despite $L$ and $\Pi$ being different objects, the former being an operator while the second is a bilinear form, they share the same matrix. This shows that somehow, the second fundamental form/shape operator is $-2$ times the Hessian matrix. I believe the $-$ comes from the definition of the shape operator and the $2$ from the normalisation of $\nabla f$.
Another instance where I see the appearence of the Hessian is as follows: We have \begin{align}\Pi(X_p,X_p) & = \langle L(X_p),X_p\rangle ,\\
& = \langle - \sum_{i=1}^n X_pN^i\partial_{i,p}, \sum_{j=1}^{n}X^i(p)\partial_{i,p}\rangle,\\
& = -\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}X^i(p)X^j(p)\partial_{i,p}^2f\langle \partial_i,\partial_j\rangle,\\
& = -\sum_{i=1}^{n}X^i(p)^2\partial^2_if(p).
\end{align}Notice that in the last line we have the second derivative appearing.
Question: How exactly are the Hessian and the shape operator/second fundamental form related?
Thank you in advance!

$M$ is $1$-dimensional, so $T_pM$ is also a $1$-dimensional vector space, so the matrix of the shape-operator should just be a. single number.

@peek-a-boo True. I will change $f$ accordingly so that we have $S^2$. Thank you

Regardless of your specific example’s typo, here’s the general relationship:

Theorem.
Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $\Sigma$ a (non-empty) regular level set of a smooth function $f:M\to\Bbb{R}$, and let $N:=\frac{\text{grad}(f)}{\|\text{grad}(f)\|_g}$ be the unit normal for the hypersurface $\Sigma$, and the gradient being taken relative to $g$. Then,
\begin{align}
\langle S_N(\cdot),\cdot\rangle_g&=\langle \mathrm{I\!I}(\cdot,\cdot),N\rangle_g=-\frac{\text{Hess}_f(\cdot,\cdot)}{\|\text{grad}(f)\|_g}.
\end{align}

Here, $S_N$ is the shape-operator relative to the normal $N$, and $\mathrm{I\!I}(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the vector second fundamental form (so taking the inner product with $N$ gives us the scalar version) and $\text{Hess}_f=D^2f$ is the Hessian of the function $f$ (where $D$ is the Levi-Civita connection of $(M,g)$).
The first equal sign here is one of the many equivalent definitions of the shape-operator/scalar second fundamental form. To prove the equivalence with the last term, we use the formula $S_N(x_p)=-D_{x_p}N$ together with the explicit formula for $N$, and just differentiate.

Exactly, that's what I was looking for. Thank you!

Note that this question has been asked and answered before, quite a while ago :)
